# How to place the data that is coming from the backend horizontally in bootstrap horizontal cards

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, api, bootstrap-4

In my angular application I have created the dashboard page and I have called the API For signals(signal-1,singal-2..etc that are changed dynamically)

To display that data I have created the bootstrap horizontal card.But I am unable to place that data as inline list items(show horizontal data) in horizontal card.

**.component.html**

```
<ul class="list-group" style="background-color:#252525;color:white">
        <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #252525;" *ngFor="let y of signals" >
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-horizontal">
              <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                <img class="sgl"
                  src="assets/img/img.png.png"
                  height="100" width="100" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{y.name}}</h5>
              
<h5 class="card-text text-muted" style="font-size:12px;">{{y.signal}}80.13

</h5>
<h5 class="card-text text-muted" style="font-size:12px;">{{y.signaltype}}

</h5>
</div>
     </div>
           
          </div>
        </li>
       </ul>
```

**Now I have to show the data items (dynamically changed or increased from the backend)those are y.name,y.signaltype,y.signal.. as horizontally with in the card.**

But I have tried many ways can anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tags you provided for the question i asume you are using bootstrap v4 so i looked up the docs and didn't found the class card-horizontal you're using. Here's the example they provide for horizontal cards

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#horizontal